# Send values from model as parameters in function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view with a `GridMVC` and two buttons, in which I'm displaying several parameters of the model, and the buttons Edit or Delete the item in that row.

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Named("eventsGrid").Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add(model => model.Summary)
        .Titled("Nombre");
    columns.Add(model => model.Description)
        .Titled("Descripción");
    columns.Add(model => model.StartDate)
        .Titled("Fecha Inicio");
    columns.Add(model => model.EndDate)
        .Titled("Fecha Fin");
    columns.Add()
        .Sanitized(false)
        .Encoded(false)
        .SetWidth(30)
        .RenderValueAs(model => (@Html.ActionLink("Editar", "EditEvent", "Home", new { eventId = model.EventID, calendarId = model.CalendarID }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" }).ToHtmlString()));
    columns.Add()
       .Sanitized(false)
       .Encoded(false)
       .SetWidth(30)
    .RenderValueAs(model => (@Html.ActionLink("Borrar", "Delete", "Home", new { eventId = model.EventID, calendarId = model.CalendarID }, new {@class = "btn btn-default"}).ToHtmlString()));
```

What I want to do is that when I click the Delete button, an alert appears to confirm that you want to delete the item, so I made this function in a `.js` file:

```
function confirmDelete(EventID, CalendarID) {
    if (confirm('¿Desea borrar este evento?'))
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Delete","Home")',
            data: { eventId: EventID, calendarId: CalendarID }
        })
    } else {
        // Do nothing!
    }
}
```

I changed it to look like this:

```
.RenderValueAs(model => @<button onclick="confirmDelete('model.EventID','model.CalendarID')" class='btn btn-default'>Borrar</button>);
```

but this makes the values in the function literally model.EventID and model.CalendarID, and I can't use `@model.EventID` as it's already inside an `@`. I also tried with an answer from [How to pass a model field to a Javascript function in a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677107/how-to-pass-a-model-field-to-a-javascript-function-in-a-view):

```
.RenderValueAs(model => @<button onclick="confirmDelete('" + model.EventID "')" class='btn btn-default'>Borrar</button>);
```

But this doesn't even call the function.

Which is the correct form to write the models parameters to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an HtmlString:

```
.RenderValueAs(model => new HtmlString("<button onclick='confirmDelete(" + model.EventID + ", " + model.CalendarID + ")' class='btn btn-default'>Borrar</button>"));
```